# WHERE date_field OPERATOR Month/Day/(Variable Year)

Tags: t-sql, date, sql-server-2012, content-management-system, where-clause

I am trying to pull invoices that are greater than or equal to October 1 (Variable Year) for every year's renewal season. I can hard code this every year, but I'd like to not have to do this because the SQL code is embedded in a child form of a CMS (netFORUM Enterprise) and run through another application and that's too many parts to keep up.

So, the hard code starting in 2016 would look like this:

```
WHERE my_date_field >= '10/01/2016'
```

**NOTE, I would run the query with this code a few times starting October 2016 and throughout the months of 2017 before October 2017.** Keep in mind that some old invoices may still be present on their account from two years back (10/1/2015), which I don't want to appear in my results.

I've pondered through a few types of method, both can't quite get it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: EDIT: I made some edits to help understand this better. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @SPlatten - SQL Server 2012

Comment: [`DateFromParts()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is half the answer. If you can calculate the appropriate year based on `Year( GetDate() )` then Bob's your uncle.

Comment: just use a where filter (like in Gordon Bell's answer) for either a check on greater than such a date or between two dates.

Comment: Is the column really a `Date` datatype, i.e. without a time? Otherwise you need a little extra fiddling to get the last day included properly.

Comment: Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE my_date_field BETWEEN 
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1) + '-10-01')
AND CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(GETDATE())) + '-09-30')
```

or for SQL Server 2012 and later:

```
WHERE my_date_field BETWEEN 
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1, 10, 01)
AND DATEFROMPARTS (YEAR(GETDATE()), 09, 30)
```

and as HABO suggested, if my_date_field includes Time, don't use BETWEEN but >= and <, like:

```
WHERE my_date_field >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1, 10, 01)
AND my_date_field < DATEFROMPARTS (YEAR(GETDATE()), 10, 01)
```

Comment: Updated so my_date_field Index, if any, will be used.

Comment: You might want to switch to `DateFromParts()` for various reasons. Kudos for changing your original answer to make it [SARGABLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Comment: @Gordon Bell - Thanks... So I used the original code before your major edits and got what I needed plus some more that I actually needed (relative to my hard code - kind of weird), but I received no results (just columns) for the third part you and HABO recommended. 

> scratching head <

Comment: Ah typo. Try now.

Comment: @ Gordon Bell - The correction with the typo provided the same results as the hard code, which is what this post asked and what I needed. THANK YOU VERY MUCH! ... 

Btw, I figured out why that original typo corrected code you shared (before your major edit/addition of the three versions) provided more results than the hard code. My overall code was to pull in current members (hints the renewal) and not new to-be members with a first time invoice. When I added the code with my other WHERE conditions I forgot to put both sides of the OR in parenthesis... WHERE (ME = DUH OR ME =DOH) =P

Answer (score 0):

You can split the day, month, year and then replace the year with current one.

```
SELECT my_date_field WHERE my_date_field >= CAST(
      CAST(DAY(my_date_field) AS NVARCHAR(2)) + '/' +
      CAST(MONTH(my_date_field) AS NVARCHAR(2)) + '/' + 
      CAST(YEAR(GETDATE())) AS DATE)
```

OR you can simply replace the year portion to the current one.

```
SELECT my_date_field WHERE my_date_field >= 
    REPLACE(my_date_field, YEAR(my_date_field), YEAR(GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Thanks, but the 3rd section from the checked answered worked.